# Достаточно ли одного соединения к базе данных?

Tags: golang, база-данных, postgresql

Есть код (с изъятиями) веб-приложения. Приложение отрывает при запуске соединение с базой данных. При запросе на отображение какой-нибудь страницы изпользуется уже заранее открытое соединение. Правильно ли открывать одно-единственное соединение на все запросы или нужно открывать на каждый запрос новое соединение?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
)

var db *sql.DB

// Здесь функции использующие соединение с базой данных db

func main() {
    db, _ = sql.Open("postgres", "...")
    defer db.Close()

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Если приложение работает в одном потоке - нормально, если нет - не нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда, если нет непреодолимых препятствий, используйте одно постоянное соединение. Открытие соединения с сервером баз данных - весьма "дорогая" операция.

Comment: И тем не менее - если приложение работает в виде - запрос - создать поток, в потоке запросы к бд, логично открывать новое соединение дабы не было простоев, иначе будет беда

Answer (score 3):

> Правильно ли открывать одно-единственное соединение на все запросы или нужно открывать на каждый запрос новое соединение?

Если под каждым запросом вы имеете ввиду HTTP-запрос, то да, на каждый HTTP-запрос нужно открывать новое соединение. Иначе вы рискуете:

- Одним тяжелым запросом к БД заблокировать все остальные запросы. (Как я понял, это и имел ввиду [[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope))
- Полностью нарушить работу транзакций, т.к., если один клиент откроет транзакцию, запросы от всех клиентов будут работать в рамках этой транзакции со всеми вытекающими от сюда последствиями.

Однако, соединение с БД действительно не самая дешевая операция, по этому открывать соединения на каждый чих тоже не стоит. Лучше всего открывать соединение непосредственно перед первым запросом к БД и закрывать по окончанию HTTP-запроса.

Так-же, в некоторых случаях, можно сэкономить на соединениях с БД используя пул соединений. Однако, этим следует пользоваться с большой осторожностью.

Comment: Чтобы автор вопроса понимал - с большой осторожностью значит хорошо тестировать =)

Comment: хм... а вот иностранные специалисты считают, что :

_"The best way is to create the database once at app start-up, and use this handle afterwards. Additionnaly, the sql.DB type is safe for 
 concurrent use, so you don't even need mutexes to lock their use."_
[Database connection best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951543/database-connection-best-practice?rq=1)

Лучший способ - это открыть соединение при старте приложения и использовать его по мере необходимости. Так-же - sql.DB настолько хорош для параллельного использования, что можно забыть про mutex-блокировки.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно нужно смотреть по обстоятельствам - из вопроса, поставленного таким образом, не ясна специфика вашей программы, но если говорить в общем, то количество сессий нужно сводить к минимуму. Идеальный вариант - один клиент, одна сессия.